# How to read in a file into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So what I need to do is read in the file "clues.txt" and store it into a dictionary... So far I have got it to store into a list but am struggling to do it with a dictionary...

My code for reading it into a list is as shown...

```
def read_clues(clues):
#TRYS TO OPEN THE FILE "CLUES.TXT"    
    try:
        readclues = open("clues.txt","r")
        for line in readclues:
#SAME CODE AS  TASK ONE HOWEVER THIS TIME IT IS DOING IT FOR CLUES
            clues.append(line[:len(line)-1])

        for clue in clues:
            print(clue)
        readclues.close()
        return clues
#IF THE FILE CANNOT BE FOUND IT WILL PRINT "ERROR FINDING FILE"
    except:
        print("Error finding file")
```

So what's in the file clues are the letter and symbol pairings shown below...

```
A#
M*
N%
```

The next part of my program involves the dictionary. Basically what it does is replaces the words.txt file (shown below) and replace the clue pairings inside it... A demonstration is shown below...

words.txt is read in as a list as it should be...

```
#+/084&"
#3*#%#+
8%203:
,1$&
!-*%
.#7&33&
#*#71%
&-&641'2
#))85
9&330*
```

clues.txt is read in as a list at the moment but needs to be read in as a dictionary...

```
A+/084&"
A3MA%A+
8%203:
,1$&
!-M%
.A7&33&
AMA71%
&-&641'2
A))85
9&330
```

The clues have then been replaced in words.txt...

The code for this is... But this needs to be changed when reading into a dictionary...

```
#SUBSTITUTE THE LETTERS WITH SYMBOLS FROM THE CLUES
def replace_symbols(clues, words):
#SPLITS THE CLUES SO THAT THEY CAN BE REPLACED WITH THE LETTER

    for clue in clues:
        letter = clue[0]
        symbol = clue[-1]

        for index in range(len(words)):
#LOOPS THROUGH THE LIST TO FIND AN INDEX VALUE
            words[index] = words[index].replace(symbol,letter)
#RETURNS THE NEW COPY BACK TO THE ORIGINAL LIST
    return words
```

The code which I am trying but receiving errors from...

```
def read_clues(clues):
    d = {}
    with open("clues.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line[1], line[0]
            d[key] = val


def replace_symbols(clues, words):
    for word in range(len(words)):
        for key, value in d.items():
            words[word] = words[word].replace(key, value)
```

Comment: You may want to tell us what is *in* your file, and how you expect those contents to be used in a dictionary.

Comment: Have changed my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work according to the pattern of clues file you posted:

```
d = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line[1], line[0]
        d[key] = val
```

Try this for reading dictionary key value pairs and replacing symbols:

```
for word in range(len(words)):
    for key, value in d.items():
        words[word] = words[word].replace(key, value)
```

**EDIT:**

```
d = {}
def read_clues(clues):
    global d
    with open("hey.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line[1], line[0]
            d[key] = val


def replace_symbols(clues, words):
    global d
    for word in range(len(words)):
        for key, value in d.items():
            words[word] = words[word].replace(key, value)
```

Just put this code in a `.py` file and run it, it will work. What you are doing is you are trying to call a local variable `d` outside of its scope that is why you were getting the error now I have made that `d` variable global.

```
#REPLACES LETTERS 
print("======== The clues have been replaced ===========")
replace_symbols(clues, words) 
for key, value in d.items():
    print key, value #This will print the symbols and letters
```

Comment: Would you be able to look at this for me?